# Mix two audios using Xuggler's MediaTool API

Tags: xuggler

I want to read the data from two audio files and after mixing it write it to a new audio file. Both audios have the same duration, samplerate & number of channels and I want to take the left channel of audio1 and the right channel of audio2 to make an stereo output with that.

From what I can see in the **MediaTool** API demos, `onAudioSamples` gets called whenever a packet is read and decoded, but for this scenario I need to have the data of both audio1 and audio2 available when onAudioSamples is called in order to modify the right channel of the samples of audio1 with the right channel of audio2.

Can I achieve this using the **MediaTool** API? should I use the lower level API?

Should I read all the packets from both audio files (like it is done in `ConcatenateAudioAndVideo` demo) before modifying the sample data, should I read a packet from each?

```
while(reader1.readPacket() == null && reader2.readPacket());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to split audio channels in the provided [documentation](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/documentation). But the `IAudioSampler` and `IAudioResampler` can be used for audio chunks. If you start with those classes and manipulate the lower level data in `IMediaData`.